# SELECT when condition is based on a result of another SELECT

Tags: mysql, select, inner-join

Query #1 works as intended, however "smf_user_points_log.id_school_year" won't be "7" every time. This value (instead of 7) has to be a result of Query #2.

**Query #1:**

```
SELECT smf_user_points_log.id_member, smf_members.usertitle
        FROM smf_user_points_log
        INNER JOIN smf_members
        ON smf_members.id_member=smf_user_points_log.id_member
        WHERE smf_user_points_log.id_school_year = 7 AND smf_user_points_log.points >= 50 AND smf_members.date_registered < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY))
```

**Query #2:**

```
SELECT id_school_year FROM smf_settings
```

How should I rewrite Query #1 in order to get the same result? I tried various joins but unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `IN` with subquery:

```
SELECT l.id_member, 
    m.usertitle
FROM smf_user_points_log l
INNER JOIN smf_members m
    ON m.id_member=l.id_member
WHERE l.id_school_year in (SELECT id_school_year FROM smf_settings)
    AND l.points >= 50 
    AND m.date_registered < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY))
```

Also, consider using short and meaningful aliases to improve query readability.

Answer (score 0):

You can do subquery:

```
SELECT smf_user_points_log.id_member, smf_members.usertitle
    FROM smf_user_points_log
    INNER JOIN smf_members
    ON smf_members.id_member=smf_user_points_log.id_member
    WHERE smf_user_points_log.id_school_year = (SELECT id_school_year FROM smf_settings) AND smf_user_points_log.points >= 50 AND smf_members.date_registered < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY))
```

Comment: This won't work if the subquery returns multiple rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can join with the `smf_settings` table.

```
SELECT smf_user_points_log.id_member, smf_members.usertitle
FROM smf_user_points_log
INNER JOIN smf_members
    ON smf_members.id_member=smf_user_points_log.id_member
INNER JOIN smf_settings
    ON smf_user_points_logs.id_school_year = smf_settings.id_school_year
WHERE smf_user_points_log.points >= 50 
    AND smf_members.date_registered < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY))
```